# FlatList ref scrollToIndex is not a function

Tags: react-native, animation, reference, undefined, react-native-flatlist

I am facing what seems to be a long-lasting issue in react native.
I am using Expo SDK35 with RN version 0.59. I have not updated to Expo SDK36 / RN 0.60 yet, due to large code base, but I could update if that makes up for a solution to my issue.

I have an `Animated.View` component that has a `FlatList` child, and I am unable to use the static methods (`scrollToIndex()` in particular) that should be available on the FlatList reference. See the next example code:

```
class Example extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.myRef = null;
    }

    componentDidUpdate = () => {
        /*
            somewhere in code outside this class, a re-render triggers
            and passes new props to this class.
            I do have props change detection, and some more other code,
            but I have removed it in order to minimize the code example here
        */

        // This call throws:
        // TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...this._scrollRef.scrollTo...')
        this.myRef.scrollToIndex({
            animated: true,
            index: 1,
            viewOffset: 0,
            viewPosition: 0.5
        });

        // Other suggested solution from SO
        // This also throws:
        // TypeError: _this.myRef.getNode is not a function. (In '_this.myRef.getNode()', '_this.myRef.getNode' is undefined)
        this.myRef.getNode().scrollToIndex({
            animated: true,
            index: 1,
            viewOffset: 0,
            viewPosition: 0.5
        });
    }
    render = () => <Animated.View style={{ /* ... some animated props */ }}>
        <FlatList ref={(flatListRef) => { this.myRef = flatListRef; }}
            // more FlatList related props
        />
    </Animated.View>
}
```

I have tried to use `Animated.FlatList` instead, still throws the same errors as in the code example above.
I have also tried to use react native's `findNodeHandle()` utility function on the received `flatListRef` parameter, but it returns `null`.

I have found the same issue posted multiple times in the past here on Stack Overflow, most with no answer, or which do not work for me. These posts are also a bit old (a year or so), which is why I am posting again for the same issue.

Did anyone manage to find a solution/workaround for this issue?

### EDIT: Possible workaround

As I was playing with code, I tried to use a `ScrollView` component instead of `FlatList` - and the `scrollTo` method works!
The changes were only on the FlatList - ScrollView specific props (so, for a ScrolLView it would be childs instead of `data={[...]}` and `renderItem={()=>{ ... }}`, ect.), and the `scrollToIndex` method in componentDidMount which was replaced by `scrollTo`.
The render method of the class, with a ScrollView, now looks like this:

```
    render = () => <Animated.View style={{ /* ... some animated props */ }}>
        <ScrollView ref={(flatListRef) => { this.myRef = flatListRef; }}>
            {/*
                this.renderItem is almost the same as the
                renderItem method used on the FlatList
             */}
             { this.state.dataArray.map(this.renderItem) }
        </ScrollView>
    </Animated.View>
```

Please note that ScrollView does not have a `scrollToIndex()` method, so you'll have to cope with manually keeping track of child positions, and maybe, implement a scrollToIndex method of your own.

I am not making this the answer to my question, because the underlying issue remains. But as a workaround, maybe you can go with it and call it a day...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## TL;DR;

```
this.myRef = React.createRef();
this.myRef.current.doSomething(); // note the use of 'current'
```

## Long version:

While the idea behind what I was trying was correct, the error in my original post seems to be quite stupid. In my defense, the docs were not clear (probably...). Anyway...

`React.createRef` returns an object with a few fields on it, all of them useless for the developer (used by React in the back) - except one: `current`.
This prop holds the current reference to the underlying component that the ref is attached to. The main ref object is not usable for the purpose I meant to in my original question above.

Instead, this is how I should've used the ref correctly:

```
this.myRef.current.scrollToIndex(...)
```

#### Hold up, don't crash

Both the main `myRef` object, and the `current` field will be `null` if the component has not yet mounted, has unmounted at any point later, or if the ref cannot be attached to it for some reason. As you may know (or found out later), `null.something` will throw an error. So, to avoid it:

```
if ((this.myRef !== null) && (this.myRef.current !== null)){
    this.myRef.current.scrollToIndex(...);
}
```

#### Extra insurance

If you try to call an undefined value as a function on a field on the ref, your code will crash. This can happend if you mistakenly reuse the same ref on multiple components, or if the component you attached it to does not have that method (i.e. `View` does not have a `scrollTo` method). To fix this you have two solutions:

```
// I find this to be the most elegant solution
if ((this.myRef !== null) && (this.myRef.current !== null)) {
    if (typeof this.myRef.current.scrollToIndex === "function") {
        this.myRef.current.scrollToIndex(...);
    }
}
```

or

```
if ((this.myRef !== null) && (this.myRef.current !== null)) {
    if (typeof this.myRef.current.scrollToIndex === "function") {
        try {
            this.myRef.current.scrollToIndex(...);
        } catch (error) {
            console.warn("Something went wrong", error);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this to be useful for anyone else learning to use refs in React. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks man. I was facing this and lost three precious hours. Your solution fixed it. 
Thanks again... @cristian

Answer (score 1):

**With Animated.ScrollView**:

- Create a ref to your FlatList (the old way only works):

`<ScrollView ref={ (ref) => (this.MyRef=ref) } />`

- Access `scrollToIndex`  using `this.myRef.getNode().scrollToIndex`

`Animated.FlatList` is currently not working unfortunately...

**With FlatList**:

- Create a ref to your FlatList by:

`<FlatList ref={ this.flatListRef } />`

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.flatListRef = React.createRef();
  }
```

- Access `scrollToIndex`  using `this.flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex`

Also make sure to wrap your code inside an if statement like:

```
 if (this.myRef.getNode()) { this.flatListRef.getNode().scrollToIndex(); }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I have tried both `FlatList` and `Animated.FlatList` ways, it always throws with either `this.myRef.scrollToIndex is not a function` or `this.myRef.getNode is not a function`. :(

Comment: plz follow the steps in `Animated.FlatList` ... and try to `console.log(this.flatListRef.getNode())` in your `componentDidMount` method

Comment: I did follow the steps you described, and I have also tried a mix of Animated.FlatList and FlatList, getNode() and direct calls on the reference. With getNode() it throws inside the if statement. without getNode() it throws on the reference just as I described initially.

The good news is - I can use a `ScrollView` instead. Placing a ref on the ScrollView and trying to use it with the same code as for a FlatList (except for renderItem, data, and other FlatList related props), it works with no issue.

I am not sure why, doesn't make sense to me, but hey... it may be a solution...

Comment: I tried `Animated.FlatList` before and it didn't work ... bug ... the issue is -> Replacing your FlatList  with ScrollView is that it will cause a drop in performance (FlatList is more optimized... )

Comment: I know about the performance drop, however, I am drawing very few childs (4 to be exact), and I am only programmatically scrolling them when needed, which hopefully does not affect performance that much. But still, thank you for trying to help me :)

Comment: great it works perfectly for your use-case... and you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

o do not know if this will help you... it scroll to a especific item in the list:

```
/*Example to Scroll to a specific position in scrollview*/
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import react in our project

import {
  View,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
//import all the components we needed

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    //Array of Item to add in Scrollview
    this.items = [
      'zero',
      'one',
      'two',
      'three',
      'four',
      'five',
      'six',
      'seven',
      'eight',
      'nine',
      'ten ',
      'eleven',
      'twelve',
      'thirteen',
      'fourteen',
      'fifteen',
      'sixteen',
      'seventeen',
      'eighteen',
      'nineteen',
      'twenty ',
      'twenty-one',
      'twenty-two',
      'twenty-three',
      'twenty-four',
      'twenty-five',
      'twenty-six',
      'twenty-seven',
      'twenty-eight',
      'twenty-nine',
      'thirty',
      'thirty-one',
      'thirty-two',
      'thirty-three',
      'thirty-four',
      'thirty-five',
      'thirty-six',
      'thirty-seven',
      'thirty-eight',
      'thirty-nine',
      'forty',
    ];
    //Blank array to store the location of each item
    this.arr = [];
    this.state = { dynamicIndex: 0 };
  }
  downButtonHandler = () => {
    if (this.arr.length >= this.state.dynamicIndex) {
      // To Scroll to the index 5 element
      this.scrollview_ref.scrollTo({
        x: 0,
        y: this.arr[this.state.dynamicIndex],
        animated: true,
      });
    } else {
      alert('Out of Max Index');
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            backgroundColor: '#1e73be',
            padding: 5,
          }}>
          <TextInput
            value={String(this.state.dynamicIndex)}
            numericvalue
            keyboardType={'numeric'}
            onChangeText={dynamicIndex => this.setState({ dynamicIndex })}
            placeholder={'Enter the index to scroll'}
            style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white', padding: 10 }}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={0.5}
            onPress={this.downButtonHandler}
            style={{ padding: 15, backgroundColor: '#f4801e' }}>
            <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Go to Index</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <ScrollView
          ref={ref => {
            this.scrollview_ref = ref;
          }}>
          {/*Loop of JS which is like foreach loop*/}
          {this.items.map((item, key) => (
            //key is the index of the array
            //item is the single item of the array
            <View
              key={key}
              style={styles.item}
              onLayout={event => {
                const layout = event.nativeEvent.layout;
                this.arr[key] = layout.y;
                console.log('height:', layout.height);
                console.log('width:', layout.width);
                console.log('x:', layout.x);
                console.log('y:', layout.y);
              }}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>
                {key}. {item}
              </Text>
              <View style={styles.separator} />
            </View>
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 30,
  },
  separator: {
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#707080',
    width: '100%',
  },

  text: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#606070',
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```

if i completly wrong, tell me...

Comment: Thank you, however, the issue is not about *how* to scroll to some index; the issue is that the ScrollView or FlatList reference that is returned from the ref attribute on these components is an *invalid reference*, or, it is not a reference at all (null is returned). Thus, this makes it impossible to call any of the static scrollTo*...* methods because there isn't something to make the call on.

Answer (score 0):

Because ScrollView has no `scrollToOffset` function and It has only `scrollTo` function.

So let use function `scrollTo` with ScrollView or `scrollToOffset` with FlatList and it works normal.

Comment: That was not the issue, I was initially using a FlatList which has a `scrollToIndex` method. I have posted the correct solution to my problem now, check my answer above :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with 'KeyboardAwareFlatList' this worked nicely:
https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/issues/372

In short, use useRef and use the `innerRef` property of the `KeyboardAwareFlatList` rather than the `ref` property.